# function if_else show false must a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

there is dataframe `final_0` , i want to mutate new variable but `if_else(amount==value,name,NULL)` show error message as `Caused by error in if_else():! false must be a vector, not NULL` 。 How to handle it ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
table_base <- data.frame(cat=c("a","b","c","d"))

table_a <- data.frame(cat=c("a","b"),
                      value=c(1,2))

table_b <- data.frame(cat=c("a","c","d"),
                      value=c(7,9,10))

final_0 <- reduce(list(table_base,table_a,table_b),left_join,by='cat') %>% 
  mutate(amount = dplyr::coalesce(!!!select(.,contains("value"))))

final_0 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c('cat','amount')) %>% 
   mutate(value_from=if_else(amount==value,name,NULL))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` doesn't have any length,

```
> length(NULL)
[1] 0
```

but `if_else` requires all arguments to be of same length.  Use `NA` instead of `NULL`.  According to `?if_else`

> A vector with the same size as condition and the same type as the common type of true, false, and missing.

```
final_0 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c('cat','amount'), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(value_from=if_else(amount==value,name,NA_character_))
```

Comment: Thanks for you help . Additional , if use ‘ok’ for  FALSE value [if_else(amount==value,name,'ok')] , the result is only include one 'ok' and others is NA , how to fix it  ? Thanks! @akrun

Comment: @anderwyang The reason is that you have some `NA` already in `value` column,  I used `values_drop_na = TRUE` in the `pivot_longer` to remove the NA.  what happens is `==` returns `NA` if there is an NA.  Instead use `%in%` which returns FALSE for `NA` elements i.e. `amount %in% value`